# Flutter apk file building taking huge time

Tags: flutter, dart, release-apk

I am using Android Studio to run Flutter. I have 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD. But whenever I am going to generate an apk file, it's taking an unlimited time. I have tried all possible command like:

```
flutter build apk --release
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
flutter build apk --build-name=1.0 --build-number=1
```

But still, the apk is not generating. It is showing:

```
    Building with sound null safety 
`Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...`                               \
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found something interesting here. After commanding mentioned command, if I do not close the terminal it's building nonstop. But if I close the terminal and let it go doing my other work, it executes very quickly. I do not know why, but it happens several times here for me.

Comment: I noticed something similar.  I was starting the build process, then going off and doing some other task in another window which appears to be stalling the build process.  I realised that if i start the build command then just back away (i didn't touch the keyboard or mouse after pressing enter to start the build) - the build then succeed quickly.  Might be a fluke!

Answer (score 1):

first use this command

```
flutter clean
```

and then

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

this command is enough for generating all type apk

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was solved by deleting a large text file (approx. 25 MB).
After that, build app was done without any problems. I had used this file to save some information through Getstorage package.